# Is Jar file need for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in the java standalone client program

Tags: java

My java program was developed in eclipse with no syntax error occurred before I executed the program, but when I executed the program, it's show me some error message which listed below, I only have one java program running in my eclipse and don't involve any XML,PHP program. I am doing a standalone Java client that are able to send the file to the server via the server URL plus it's port number through API call.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/util/Args
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
    at SentFile.main(SentFile.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I had done some checking on the jar file for **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** and I found out **org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody**,**org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody,org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody** had been included in my eclipse class path. I cant find either jar file for **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** error which I had searched some information in google, some suggestion describe that is a jar file missing. Is it true because I can't find the jar file online. I am bit new to Java programming
 [This](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html) is my reference link

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    public class SentFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.25:8008/file");
         // File file = new File("testScanFile.txt");
         //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("testScanFile.txt"));
          HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                   .addPart("bin", bin)
                   .build();
           post.setEntity(reqEntity);
          //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
         // post.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
          }
         }

    }
```

Comment: @RobAu - I had edited the detail of the question, it's might not similar to the one you shared with me

Comment: You need the `httpcore` `.jar` on your classpath. Please use the *same* version as you used in Eclipse.

Comment: I am not sure about it. But I once tried this and httpCore 4.2.3 was not working. But once i upgraded httpCore to 4.4 (greater than 4.3 ), I started working. Still not sure. You can try and see the results.